# K fold cross validation in yolo v4 with darknet

Tags: darknet, yolov4

I am new to the field of deep learning. I need to test a trained model with darknet neural network, using yolo v4.
During the training I performed the division of the dataset into 80% training test and 20% test set.
I would like to know if there was a way to use the k fold cross validation methodology with yolo.